# I can't find why some page cause 403 error after adjust "CSRF"

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, csrf

I adjusted CSRF on my project. but some reasons It cause 403 error in some pages. I was not able to find the wrong code or wrong way.

this is example what I used and caused 403 error. of course I also used same code in other pages . but some of pages cause 403 error and some of pages not.

```js
    // Excel
    function fn_excel() {
        var form = $('form[name="Form"]');

        $(form).attr({
            action : "${ctx}/aaa/bbb/cccExcel.do"

        }).submit();

    }
```

my situation is even though I used the same code, some pages working very well.

this is I added code where It needs for "CSRF".

```
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName }">

<meta name="_csrf_parameter" content="${_csrf.parameterName }">

<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token }">
```

setting for AJAX I also added this code.

```
javascript
//ajax setting : CSRF + check Login

(function($) {
    var header = $('meta[name="_csrf_header"]').attr("content");

    var token = $('meta[name="_csrf"]').attr("content");

    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend : function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);

            xhr.setRequestHeader("AJAX", true);

            if ($('div.loading').length) {
                $("div.loading").show();

            }

        },

        complete : function() {
            if ($('div.loading').length) {
                $("div.loading").hide();

            }

        },

        error : function(xhr) {
            if (xhr.status == 401) {
                alert("This is an unauthenticated account.");

            } else if (xhr.status == 403) {
                menu("/aa.do", "00000");

            } else {
                alert("An error has occurred.");

            }

        }

    });

})(jQuery);
```

also, I added code in `context-security.xml`

context-security.xml

```
    <!-- CSRF  -->

    <csrf request-matcher-ref="csrfSecurityRequestMathcer" />



<!-- adjust CSRF Filter -->

<beans:bean id="csrfSecurityRequestMathcer" class="aa.bb.cc.dd.CsrfSecurityRequestMathcer" />
```

this is the java class `CsrfSecurityRequestMathcer`

```java
public class CsrfSecurityRequestMathcer implements RequestMatcher {


    private Pattern allowedMethods = Pattern.compile("^(GET|HEAD|TRACE|OPTIONS)$");

    private RegexRequestMatcher unprotectedMatcher = new RegexRequestMatcher("/unprotected", null);

    @Override

    public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {

       // don't adjust CSRF if "GET, HEAD, TRACE, OPTIONS" this way
        if(allowedMethods.matcher(request.getMethod()).matches()){
            return false;

        }

        // Removed login CSRF due to SSO linkage 

        if("/m/loPo.do".equals(request.getRequestURI())) {
            return false;

        }

        return !unprotectedMatcher.matches(request);

    }

}
```

I wrote like that.
I wanted to explain more detail. but I don't know where is the wrong part of it. 
so I leave like this.

Comment: Hey, did you double check that the access right (rwx) are given correctly, bc if not it could be outside the code.

Comment: I added thid code in action after .do "?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}"
and It works very well

Comment: oh well, "?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}" which is GET method is work.
but  POST method is not work.
I have no idea about it.